# define - constant or literal Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, constants, literals

We have the following code (in the .h. or .m file of Objective-C app)

```
#define SQUARE_SIZE 28
#define APP_DELEGATE [[UIApplication sharedApplication] appDelegate]
```

are both of them [constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28programming%29)
or [literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_science%29) ?

What is their proper name? And it they are literals as I suspect, why most call them constants :)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're neither, they're macros.

A constant would look like this:

```
const int square_size = 28;
```

The difference between a macro and a constant here is that the constant has a *type* while a macro is simply some text fragment that gets inserted at the place where it's mentioned before the compiler is parsing the source code.

And a literal is something like `28` or `@"This is a string"`, that is a value.